# What does the `with` keyword without the `match` do inside a inductive type in Coq?

Tags: coq

What does the `with` keyword without the `match` do inside a inductive type in Coq?, example:

```
Inductive Block : Type :=
  | EmptyBlk : Block
  | Blk : Statement -> Block
with Statement : Type :=
  | Assignment : string -> AExp -> Statement
  | Seq : Statement -> Statement -> Statement
  | IfElse : BExp -> Block -> Block -> Statement
  | While : BExp -> Block -> Statement.
```

I tried checking the type of `Statement` and it seems its not of type block or something...So what is the point of defining it inside another inductive type rather than by itself. At least checking the type of Statement gives Set the same as for Block...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to specify mutually recursive definitions. For example, consider the following two functions:

```
Fixpoint even (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | S n => odd n
  end
with odd (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => false
  | S n => even n
  end.
```

Here, you cannot define `even` first because it needs `odd` to be defined. You cannot define `odd` first either because it needs `even`. You need to be able to define both *at the same time* - and you do that by using the `with` keyword.

Your example is similar but defines inductive datatype rather than recursive function - `Statement` uses `Block` in its definition and `Block` uses `Statement`. Hence, `with` to define them both at the same time.

Note that this `with` is completely different keyword than `with` from the `match` expressions. In fact, they belong to two different languages: the former one is part of [Vernacular](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html) whereas the latter is part of [Gallina](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html).